# How create flutter app and receive notifications from beacon device?

Tags: flutter, notifications, beacon

I'm confused with this thing. Exist any way to create an app with flutter to RECEIVE notification from beacon devices? (not recognized other beacons devices )!

I didn't find any application example. I just found packaged on flutter but I don't understand how to use and also if the packages are correct for the purpose that i want.

Please explain me :) Thank you!

Comment: I saw this couple of weeks ago, hope it can bring some light about this. 
 https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-turn-your-phone-into-a-beacon-with-flutter-47619bfa9963

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As I understand after many searches the link you mention is to TURN your device TO beacon. I don't need that because I've already a beacon device. I want to get notification from a beacon device.